# tensorflow python expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 28, 5)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a complete newbie to tensorflow, trying to learn about it and solve a problem.  I tried a lot of tutorials but they all talked about the same classify image or mnist stuff, so I followed the documentation and tried to figure something out.

The goal is to find a pattern to predict the result when the input is [[1000,10, 5, 3, 1744...etc.  There are only 5 cases when the value is 300 400, 500, 600, 700, with shape 28,5 and the result for each is 28,2 list.  The data is loaded from file and assigned to tf.tensor.

Here's my code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(28, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(28, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(28))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(newData, newResults, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=5)
```

newData:

```
[[[300, 10, 5, 3, 1744], [300, 10, 5, 5, 2848], [300, 10, 5, 4, 2418], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1152], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1126], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1897], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1089], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1581], [300, 10, 5, 4, 1793], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1525], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1529], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1052], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1556], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1569], [300, 10, 5, 5, 2873], [300, 10, 5, 4, 2269], [300, 10, 5, 3, 3003], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1310], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1464], [300, 10, 5, 3, 2807], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1262], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1734], [300, 10, 5, 2, 2709], [300, 10, 5, 3, 2234], [300, 10, 5, 3, 1961], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1594], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1836], [300, 10, 5, 2, 1345]], 
[[400, 10, 5, 3, 1744], [400, 10, 5, 5, 2848], [400, 10, 5, 4, 2418], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1152], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1126], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1897], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1089], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1581], [400, 10, 5, 4, 1793], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1525], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1529], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1052], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1556], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1569], [400, 10, 5, 5, 2873], [400, 10, 5, 4, 2269], [400, 10, 5, 3, 3003], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1310], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1464], [400, 10, 5, 3, 2807], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1262], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1734], [400, 10, 5, 2, 2709], [400, 10, 5, 3, 2234], [400, 10, 5, 3, 1961], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1594], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1836], [400, 10, 5, 2, 1345]], 
[[500, 10, 5, 3, 1744], [500, 10, 5, 5, 2848], [500, 10, 5, 4, 2418], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1152], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1126], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1897], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1089], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1581], [500, 10, 5, 4, 1793], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1525], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1529], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1052], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1556], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1569], [500, 10, 5, 5, 2873], [500, 10, 5, 4, 2269], [500, 10, 5, 3, 3003], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1310], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1464], [500, 10, 5, 3, 2807], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1262], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1734], [500, 10, 5, 2, 2709], [500, 10, 5, 3, 2234], [500, 10, 5, 3, 1961], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1594], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1836], [500, 10, 5, 2, 1345]], 
[[600, 10, 5, 3, 1744], [600, 10, 5, 5, 2848], [600, 10, 5, 4, 2418], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1152], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1126], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1897], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1089], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1581], [600, 10, 5, 4, 1793], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1525], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1529], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1052], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1556], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1569], [600, 10, 5, 5, 2873], [600, 10, 5, 4, 2269], [600, 10, 5, 3, 3003], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1310], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1464], [600, 10, 5, 3, 2807], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1262], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1734], [600, 10, 5, 2, 2709], [600, 10, 5, 3, 2234], [600, 10, 5, 3, 1961], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1594], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1836], [600, 10, 5, 2, 1345]], 
[[700, 10, 5, 3, 1744], [700, 10, 5, 5, 2848], [700, 10, 5, 4, 2418], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1152], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1126], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1897], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1089], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1581], [700, 10, 5, 4, 1793], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1525], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1529], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1052], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1556], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1569], [700, 10, 5, 5, 2873], [700, 10, 5, 4, 2269], [700, 10, 5, 3, 3003], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1310], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1464], [700, 10, 5, 3, 2807], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1262], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1734], [700, 10, 5, 2, 2709], [700, 10, 5, 3, 2234], [700, 10, 5, 3, 1961], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1594], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1836], [700, 10, 5, 2, 1345]]]
```

newResult:

```
[[[29.0, 8.92], [52.0, 21.67], [41.0, 14.38], [7.0, 1.49], [26.0, 8.25], [18.0, 4.53], [24.0, 6.61], [21.0, 9.54], [17.0, 5.53], [27.0, 9.61], [11.0, 0.35], [22.0, 8.11], [7.0, 1.22], [36.0, 15.49], [57.0, 31.44], [43.0, 16.52], [34.0, 11.46], [15.0, 2.49], [20.0, 2.34], [16.0, 4.86], [10.0, 0.8], [8.0, 0.4], [1.0, 0.0], [30.0, 7.57], [24.0, 7.21], [5.0, 0.58], [14.0, 0.73], [4.0, 0.15]], 
[[45.0, 8.17], [100.0, 43.28], [54.0, 16.05], [10.0, 2.77], [37.0, 8.86], [27.0, 6.12], [33.0, 9.13], [34.0, 14.03], [20.0, 5.06], [45.0, 15.42], [21.0, 0.69], [26.0, 8.83], [11.0, 2.14], [44.0, 17.74], [73.0, 43.39], [43.0, 18.8], [46.0, 21.56], [29.0, 9.16], [21.0, 3.76], [20.0, 7.39], [16.0, 2.54], [1.0, 1.63], [1.0, 0.02], [28.0, 12.14], [30.0, 12.35], [7.0, 1.18], [19.0, 3.29], [4.0, 0.16]], 
[[59.0, 18.74], [100.0, 75.18], [69.0, 32.13], [11.0, 3.04], [49.0, 15.76], [30.0, 10.33], [45.0, 14.51], [43.0, 20.82], [37.0, 8.2], [69.0, 24.53], [1.0, 0.3], [38.0, 12.57], [1.0, 3.67], [65.0, 24.77], [91.0, 57.39], [53.0, 18.22], [47.0, 27.07], [34.0, 16.31], [25.0, 5.39], [31.0, 11.5], [23.0, 5.73], [19.0, 4.11], [2.0, 0.11], [35.0, 15.52], [41.0, 18.15], [7.0, 1.48], [25.0, 7.53], [3.0, 0.14]], 
[[80.0, 30.29], [100.0, 85.22], [94.0, 52.73], [11.0, 2.45], [72.0, 30.7], [46.0, 14.75], [70.0, 22.81], [50.0, 28.26], [40.0, 14.19], [60.0, 26.82], [14.0, 0.28], [45.0, 19.1], [16.0, 4.72], [82.0, 40.98], [100.0, 78.96], [66.0, 27.05], [67.0, 31.09], [34.0, 16.92], [23.0, 7.03], [48.0, 21.28], [27.0, 8.19], [21.0, 3.95], [2.0, 0.17], [43.0, 19.96], [55.0, 23.54], [8.0, 1.47], [28.0, 12.04], [4.0, 0.13]], 
[[95.0, 38.09], [100.0, 92.88], [99.0, 58.96], [13.0, 3.54], [96.0, 45.78], [33.0, 12.05], [87.0, 38.11], [62.0, 34.97], [48.0, 15.49], [84.0, 33.13], [10.0, 0.09], [63.0, 25.52], [16.0, 4.87], [100.0, 55.9], [100.0, 91.32], [90.0, 34.24], [96.0, 45.36], [37.0, 15.13], [27.0, 9.28], [49.0, 26.3], [30.0, 10.92], [22.0, 3.72], [3.0, 0.14], [67.0, 24.82], [73.0, 31.32], [8.0, 1.36], [31.0, 15.03], [4.0, 0.2]]]
```

Getting this error when I run it:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1536, in fit
    validation_split=validation_split)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 992, in _standardize_user_data
    class_weight, batch_size)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1117, in _standardize_weights
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 323, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 28, 5)
```

I know my model definitely has something wrong with it, but I can't quite figure out what.  I have trouble finding information other than the afore mentioned examples.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written starts with a Dense layer of 28 neurons expecting an array of shape `(*, 5)`. The error message shows that the shape it is receiving is `(5, 28, 5).

Looking at your data, it is shape `(5, 28, 5)`. Maybe you have an extra set of brackets?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how my data should look like?  I have 5 samples, and each one has (28, 5).  The results are (28, 2).  All I can find are pieces of how each function work, but I can't find how to put it together.

Comment: Oh, so you're trying to use 2D input. In that case, you should just flatten the samples to 1D (`5, 140`) before you use it and use `input_shape=(140,)`. Those dense layers are fully connected so their topology (1d, 2d, whatever) doesn't really mean anything - every neuron in layer 1 has a connection to every neuron in layer 2.